# Find capital letter in BBEdit

Tags: find, letter, bbedit

I am working in BBEdit to clean up text in "textfactory"

But I have run into a problem. In the text below there are two periods "."

Ex.
afghanhund, borzoi, greyhound. sloughi, whippet. Thomas M Hehir, Irland

A period before space and capital letter should be a colon. All other periods should be a comma.

afghanhund, borzoi, greyhound**,** sloughi, whippet**:** Thomas M Hehir, Irland

How can I search for any capital letter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps.

[image]

A period before space and capital letter should be a colon.

1. Use Find <kbd>⌘+F</kbd>.

   - Check the `Case sensitive` and `Grep` checkboxes.
   - Find pattern : `\.(\s+[A-Z])`.
   - Replace pattern : `:\1`.
   - Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

   [image]

All other periods should be a comma.

2. Do a simple Replace

   - Uncheck the `Case sensitive` and `Grep` checkboxes.
   - Find pattern : `.`
   - Replace pattern : `,`
   - Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

[image]